# Flex/Actionscript 3 dynamic width/height change

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, dimensions, stage

Is it possible to dynamically (*not* in the project's options) change the dimensions of the stage by using ActionScript 3?
I'd want to create a 400x300px loader, but I also want it to load animations that have bigger or smaller dimensions. I would then change the width and height of the loader to make the loaded animations fit well.
Is there any way to do that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<YourLoaderOrContainerWithAnimation top="0" bottom="0" left="0" right="0" width="100%" height="100%" minWidth="400" minHeight="300" maxWidth="400" maxHeight="300"/>
```

first of all use code.google.com/p/swfobject instead of embed tag, and yes you can directly change sizes like this.width=width_from_js; but as I remember swfobject will allow you to do this in raw js, just check it and let us know. :) thanks

Comment: Thanks for your help, but that's not exactly what I wanted. I have tested it with a 336x252px loader and 400x300px animation.
The loader used the ExternalInterface class to call my Javascript function ResizeContainer(). When the function resized the container, the loaded animation didn't show up correctly - it was just stretched to 400x300, but a big part of it has been left out of the stage.

Comment: add callback from your ResizeContainer to your Loader to change the sizes. Are you using swfobject as wrapper for flash in html?

Comment: Well, no, I use the <embed> tag with the loader placed directly in it (no Javascript here). "Add callback from your ResizeContainer to your Loader to change the sizes" - so does there exist a way to change the loader's size directly from ActionScript?

Comment: first of all use http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/ instead of **embed** tag, and yes you can directly change sizes like *this.width=width_from_js*; but as I remember swfobject will allow you to do this in raw js, just check it and let us know. :) thanks.

Comment: Well, I have finally done it. :) I had problems with setting this.width and height so I have searched a bit in Google and I have found another interesting thing - stage.scaleMode. I have set it to StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE and now I just have to change the container's size, nothing more. :) Thanks for your help anyway. And thanks for info about swfobject.

Comment: @rhino you're welcome, don't forget to rate comments and answers and have a happy coding!